# Poisson and exponential distribution problem

Tags: probability, statistics

The number of planes arriving per day at a small private airport is a random variable having a poison distribution with $\lambda= 28.8$. What's the probability that the time between two such arrivals is at least one hour?

I'm thinking that this is an exponential distribution with $\theta = \frac{1}{28.8}$. So then it would follow that I would have to find $P(X\ge \frac{1}{24}) = 1-  P(X \lt \frac{1}{24})= 1- \int_0 ^{\frac{1}{24}} 28.8e^{-28.8x} dx \approx .301$. I think this is equivalent to saying the complement of the probability that the time between arrivals is less than an hour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you say, the interarrival time is exponentially distributed with the parameter you quoted. So your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct!

---

Equivalently, you can notice that the required probability is equal to the probability that there will be no arrivals in an hour. Since, the arrivals per hour $X_h$ (and not per day) follow the Poisson distribution with $$λ_h=\frac{λ}{24}=\frac{28.8}{24}=1.2$$ you find that the requested probability is equal to $$P(X_h=0)=e^{-λ_h}\frac{λ_h^0}{0!}=e^{-1.2}=0.301194211$$

Comment: That's interesting, I was thinking about how to view this as a Poisson process as well. Thank You.

Comment: @Nid you already had it, so I did not add much. Anyway, you are welcome!